# Google Sheets, Delete 2 or more cells data if another cell has X in it

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-sheets

I have a work log that needs to be cleared at end of day but only if a packer has printed.  The department sheets have 2 cells per row, A & G, that need the data cleared if cell H has an X in it.  The "Main" sheet is also going to need 4 cells cleared and a formula reset too but if I see the script for the department sheets, I think I will be able to adjust it for the Main sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L-SK-dWUW_EyX1KxHZLrY_wf-SlxrgvW8tQo5q8ijj4/edit?usp=sharing

I have found a few scripts that will delete the entire row but that's not what I need.
This one I couldn't get to work at all:

```
function checkH_bb() {
var s, data, colH, colA, key, i;
s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dept 500");
data=s.getDataRange().getValues();
for (i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) data.shift();
colH=data.map(function(x) {return x[7];});
colA=data.map(function(x) {return x[0];});
key="x";
for (i in colH) {
if (colH[i]==key) colA[i]='';
}
s.getRange(11, 1, colA.length).setValues(colA.map(function(x) {return [x];}));
}
```

This one I didn't try because I realized I needed to keep the formulas.

```
function readRows() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[1] == 'old') {
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
}
}
};
```

There are formulas in other cells that I need to keep.  I looked into keeping the formulas if the data is deleted but I couldn't get that to work either.
This one I couldn't get to work, not sure why.

```
function myFunction() {
function clearValues(range) {
var formulas = range.getFormulas();
range.clearContent();
range.setFormulas(formulas);
}
 }
```